# lottery system pot division

Tags: javascript, math, formula, division

I making a lottery system in my web-based application, so it is in JavaScript, but my problem is more mathematical so feel free to write snippets in other language.

I want to distribute the lottery pot over winners in a natural feeling way, example:

```
var pot = 1000;
var tickets = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];
tickets = shuffleArray(tickets); //shuffle tickets for winners
//first half wins something (2 should be changeable)
var winners_count = Math.ceil(tickets.length / 2);
```

In this scenario i need a way to divide the whole pot over the 10 winners where first place gets the most and last (10th) get fewest.

```
for(var i=0; i<winners_count; i++){
    var ticket = tickets[i];
    //formula to determine percentage of pot to gain needed.
}
```

example outcome: (just to show you where it needs to go, not actual match)

```
1 - 22%
2 - 18%
3 - 14%
4 - 12%
5 - 10%
6 - 8%
7 - 7%
8 - 5%
9 - 3%
10 - 1%
```

I am quite bad at mathematics and some pointers and/or code snippets would help me a lot in solving this.

**EDIT**

Solution from Fabien Roualdes: http://jsfiddle.net/LB8YU/1/

Comment: Where did you come up with 22, 18, 14, etc...? Is it just an example you made up off the top of your head?

Comment: @JayGee I just moved around numbers until i got a total of 100%, so yeah just from the top of my head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose you to use an exponential distribution:

```
for(i=0 ; i<nrWinners ; i++){
    value = exp(-lambda*i);
    distribution[i] = value;
    sum += value;
}
for(i=0 ; i<nrWinners ; i++){
    distribution[i] /= sum;  
}
```

Lambda is a positive parameter which will permit you to choose the shape of the distribution:

- If lambda is high the first winners will have a big part of the pot;
- On the contrary, the smaller lambda is, the more the distribution will aim towards a fair division of the pot.

I hope it will help you!

EDIT: When I say lambda is high, it is already high if it is equal to 1 for 5 winners.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try to work this in and test results, ill get back to you!

Comment: Alright after trying it, I have found myself short of knowledge to use it properly. I am missing where the pot value comes in, and how it distributes 100% of it. and results are not even close to what i'd expect http://jsfiddle.net/LB8YU/ (check console) I think your idea is exactly what I need but it probably works difrently in javascript, I would appreciate it if you could help me solve this :) Thanks.

Comment: No, I tested it, all works well and you do not have to try to remove the scientific notation. But... lambda=10... your problem is here: try with lambda=0.5. In fact _lambda will depend of the number of winners and of the shape of the distribution_. For 5 winners with lambda=10, the first winner will have 99% of the pot and I think it is not what you want :)